# Play video using native code in Unity3d via NDK

Tags: android, opengl-es, unity-game-engine, android-ndk

I have a working game in Unity3D Game Engine. and I want to play a transparent video in my game. Now we have tried a few plugins, but It crashes in Nexus 5.

Is there any other way to play it in Unity3d itself?

If not, then How can I play it from native using OpenGL, and use it in Unity3D via NDK?

If it is possible then let me know the steps for that..

Comment: This is too broad a question. Can you please elaborate what steps you have tried?

Comment: I have used this plugin in unity3d.
https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/2449
but it crashes so I want to make something similar to that.

For that I have to render my video in openGL in native. then make a bridge via NDK to Unity3D to use that rendered video in Unity3D.
I just want to know steps for that procedure.